# TypeScript optional property assignment initialization

Tags: typescript

Why is Typescript (v3.7.2) not able to statically analyze a nested object assignment for an optional property in an object?

For example:

```
interface Foo {
  bar?: {
    baz: string;
  }
}

const foo: Foo = {
  bar: {
    baz: 'foobar',
  },
};

// Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
const baz1 = foo.bar.baz;

foo.bar = { baz: 'foobar'};

// No error
const baz2 = foo.bar.baz;
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will not try to infer the type of an object literal if you give it a type annotation. You explicitly declared that the type of `foo` is `Foo`; so the compiler determines the type of `foo.bar` by looking at the declaration of the type `Foo` instead of a more specific type inferred from the object literal `foo` is declared as. Type inference is only done when there is no type annotation.

If you want `foo` to have a more specific type inferred from the object literal, then remove the type annotation: write `const foo = ...` instead of `const foo: Foo = ...`.

The second example `foo.bar = { baz: 'foobar' };` is an assignment, not a declaration, so the compiler only has to check that the right-hand-side has an appropriate type for the assignment target (which it does). The compiler also does control-flow type narrowing, since it knows that `foo.bar` can't be undefined after that assignment.

Comment: It does type-checking as well as type-narrowing; but that is not inference, of course. Thank you for the correction.